# Find $\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} np^n\sum\limits_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \binom{k-1}{n-1}(1-p)^{k-n}$.

Tags: calculus, probability, limits, negative-binomial

This is very likely to be a probabilitic problem，just noting that

$$E[1/X]=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k}\binom{k-1}{n-1}p^n(1-p)^{k-n},$$
where $X$ is the random variable of **Negative-Binomial Distribution**. Thus the present limit is the very
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} nE[1/X].$$
How to go on from here? Can it be solved just by calculus **without probability**?

Comment: Note the limit expression in your title doesn't quite match the expression you provide for $E[1/X]$ (in particular, the title has an initial factor of $n$ while the $E[1/X]$ has a factor of $\frac{1}{k}$ in its summation). To help avoid potential confusion, you should either explain why they're different or have them match instead.

Comment: You have  type in the title.

Comment: Sorry, correted.